# Проблемы при работе с QThread Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, windows-7, qthread

Пишу программу на С++, используя Qt. Задача: Пользователь может указать директорию, которая состоит из других папок, а внутри этих папок находятся файлы.  Необходимо заархивировать папки с файлом и поместить архивы в другую директорию.  Я работаю с дополнительным потоком для обработки (создал класс Worker и т.п.). Все делал по примеру из документации Qt.  Проблема следующая: На моем компьютере и на компьютерах с Windows 10 все работает. Но на компьютерах с Windows 7 после обработки одной большой папки программа крашится. Ошибка: Программа не работает, код 0xc0000005. Что делать? Это проблема в коде или нужно что-то установить дополнительно? Net Framework, Visual C++ и т.п. обновлял, но ничего не помогло. Код программы прилагаю.

P.S. Если не использовать дополнительный поток, то все работает корректно. Но дополнительный поток нужен, чтобы можно было отображать прогресс обработки, то есть сколько каталогов обработано

```
#include "renamewidget.h"
#include "ui_renamewidget.h"
#include <private/qzipwriter_p.h>

QString RenameWidget::filePath;       //static field
QString RenameWidget::directoryPath;  //static field
QString RenameWidget::resultPath;     //static field

RenameWidget::RenameWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::RenameWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    filePath      = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/1.xlsx";
    directoryPath = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/2";
    resultPath    = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/3";

    connect(this, &RenameWidget::doWork, &worker, &Worker::doWork);
    connect(&worker, &Worker::workProgress, this, &RenameWidget::setText);
    worker.moveToThread(&thread);
    thread.start();
}


void RenameWidget::setText(QString message)
{
    ui->lableLoad->setText(message); // setProgress
}

void RenameWidget::on_pb_Rename_clicked()
{
        emit doWork();
}

void Worker::doWork()
{
        emit workProgress("");

        QDir dir;
        dir.setPath(RenameWidget::getDirectoryPath());
        QStringList listDir = dir.entryList(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDot | QDir::NoDotDot);

        for (int i = 0; i<listDir.size();i++)
        {
        QString article = QString::number(i);
            dir.setPath(RenameWidget::getDirectoryPath() + "/" + listDir.at(i));
            QStringList tempstr = dir.entryList(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDot | QDir::NoDotDot);
            
            QString temppath = RenameWidget::getDirectoryPath() + "/" + listDir.at(i) + "/" + tempstr .at(0);
            QString tempres  = RenameWidget::getResultPath() + "/" + "archives" + "/" + article;

            dir.mkpath(tempres);
            doArchive(temppath + "/", tempres + "/" + article + ".zip");

             emit workProgress("Обработано каталогов: " + QString::number(i+1) + "/" + QString::number(listDir.size()));
        }

        emit workProgress("Готово");
}

void Worker::doArchive(QString path, QString zippath)
{
    QZipWriter zip(zippath);

    zip.setCompressionPolicy(QZipWriter::AutoCompress);

    QDirIterator it(path, QDir::Files | QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        QString file_path = it.next();
        if (it.fileInfo().isFile())
        {
            QFile file(file_path);
            if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
                continue;
            zip.setCreationPermissions(QFile::permissions(file_path));
            QByteArray ba = file.readAll();
            zip.addFile(file_path.remove(path), ba);
        }
    }
    zip.close();
}
```

Comment: Qt::QueuedConnection?

Comment: @magrif по-умолчанию

Comment: @ДмитрийМалков, с виду всё чинно мирно… я бы сосредоточился на том, чтобы хотя бы бектрейс получить (а может и полный дамп памяти) в момент краха, чтобы понятно было, куда копать…

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а как это можно посмотреть?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, проблема точно в дополнительном потоке, т.к если его убрать и все операции выполнять в классе RenameWidget(в классе GUI), то все работает корректно

Comment: а если запустить в дебаге, то при краше дебагер куда покажет?

Comment: @ДмитрийМалков, к сожалению, точных инструкций дать не смогу… если есть возможность запустить под отладчиком на целевой системе и под ним баг воспроизводится, то он почти наверняка остановится при сегфолте… если нет, то можно обрабатывать это из приложения: на *nix системах это обчыно делается перехватом `SIGSEGV`+`backtrace()`… как это сделать на win я не подскажу… из шапки гугла: [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-automatically-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-program-crashes) советуют Windows Error Reporting, которая скорее аналог корок, чем бектрейса, но тоже сойдёт…

Comment: Кстати, из подозрительного: `file.readAll();` — если файл достаточно большой, то его будет проблематично прочитать полностью… особенно на обычной x86… ЗЫ: а ещё если `QZipWriter` — это тот, недокументированный класс самого Qt, то ни кто не гарантирует, что он должен нормально работать на всех архивах…